# VisualVM - Failed to create remote heap dump and save it

Tags: java, profiling, dump, visualvm, heap-dump

I cannot take heap dump through VisualVM. When I click "Heap Dump" button in VisualVM 2.1.2, I get the following error:
[image]

What am I doing wrong? Am I missing a setting somewhere?

Comment: I think that the heap dump was created ok. Please check the file on remote computer.

Answer (score 2):

The heap dump is fine. There is a bug in recent version of VisualVM, which checks the presence of the heap dump file on the local filesystem even though the heap dump was created on remote machine. It would be great, if you can file a bug with the description, you used above, at https://github.com/oracle/visualvm/issues. It will be fixed in VisualVM 2.1.3. Thanks.